# Backing up IMAP based email via with Mac

Tags: mac, backup, imap

I have a few years of email saved on my email hosting providers IMAP servers. I would like to make a local backup copy of all those emails for archival purposes. I also need to be able to search through this archives. Any recommendations on a program for the Mac that can accomplish this? Freeware would be best but I don't mind paying for a good program.

Requirements:

1. Storage in a cross platform format (i.e. text files)
2. Preserve IMAP folder structure
3. Able to search archives

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thunderbird might be a good answer.  It stores IMAP-downloaded folders as standard mbox files, will preserve the IMAP structure, and has a rudimentary search function.  You can also pick up your Thunderbird profile directory and put it on any other machine with Thunderbird to read it.

Answer (score 2):

OS X's Mail.app respects parts 2 and 3

Comment: And part 1, too. In 10.6 (and earlier, too, I think), each message is stored as an individual plain-text .emlx file within the .imapmbox folder.

Answer (score 0):

[Check out the `imapsync` program](http://www.linux-france.org/prj/imapsync/). It is an IMAP synchronization, copy or migration tool that is available through MacPorts.